# How to create signature for using API

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Hyperledger Fabric CA provide a bunch of API for interact with its CA server and almost request enrollment token in header to authorization.
As it mention in document, the token is consisting of two base 64 encoded parts separated by a period
 - An enrollment certificate
 - A signature over the certificate and body of request.
Currently, I generated base64 of both enrollment certificate and body request but get stuck with how to create a signature with these things.
So, how to create this token? And do Hyperledger Fabric provide any tool to complete this step?

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm in a similar position.